# combine load and resize plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, resize, load

I combine the load en the resize function in one.

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    if (window.innerWidth < 700) {
        alert('hello');
    }
}).resize();
```

But I am looking for a code in plain JavaScript (without jQuery).

How can I create this?

Comment: You're after setting up an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded` and `resize`. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener for details.

Comment: You're not combining *Load* and *Resize* but *DOM ready* and *Resize* (at least from what you provided)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by adding event listener and calling a function on resize:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", onResizeFunction);

function onResizeFunction (e){
//do whatever you want to do on resize event 
}
```

Same thing is for onLoad event:

```
window.addEventListener("load", onLoadFunction);

function onLoadFunction(e){
//do the magic you want 
}
```

If you want to trigger function on resize, when the window loads

```
window.addEventListener("load", onLoadFunction);

function onLoadFunction(e){
//do the magic you want 
onResizeFunction();// if you want to trigger resize function immediately, call it 

window.addEventListener("resize", onResizeFunction);
}

function onResizeFunction (e){
//do whatever you want to do on resize event 
}
```

Comment: how do you get the event object using this method?

Comment: @blueprintChris, just pass event as function parameter. i.e. 
`function onResizeFunction (e){
//do whatever you want to do on resize event 
}`